# How do I create an App

Tags: web-applications

If I am creating an App - a Web-App, or an App for tablets/smartphones, what should I learn? What specifically do I have to use to create an app, apart from knowing basic Web development?

Comment: This question is **waay** too broad... You have to learn the SDK for whatever device you want to create an app for. Check the manufacturer's website; most of them encourage third-party app development.

Comment: I'm confused, are you creating a web app or a smartphone app?

Comment: I'm not creating one yet - I am getting into app-development and I just wanted to know what I had to learn before I could start developing apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how a typical mobile web application could be made, you should play around with jQuery Mobile:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/

If you want to use html for creating a views in a native application, you should learn about webviews:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html

If you want to use html to generate native application, you could use tools like PhoneGap:

http://phonegap.com/